# How to set up email address on my domain

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, postfix

I realize this is a really elementary question but I can't seem to find a good answer to my question through googling.

I want to set up an email address on my domain, e.g. jason@example.com. I think I'd like it to forward to my GMail account.

I'm on Ubuntu and I already have Postfix installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using Google apps for this and just setting up forwarding. If you insist on setting up a mail server, check out this guide: http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/

Answer (score 1):

From the content of your question, I'd suggest that instead of trying to set up a mail server of your own, that you consider [setting up a Google apps account for your domain](http://lifehacker.com/5708219/why-you-should-use-google-apps-with-your-personal-domain-for-your-google-life). You can configure either account to forward to the other, as you see fit.

The process is fairly straight forward. As you've already got you domain, you need to [sign up to Google Apps](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&hlrm=en&answer=53929), then [create a couple of MX records in your registrar's control panel and point them at Google's servers](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33915). The whole process shouldn't take longer than a couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

If you want mail for your domain, there needs to be a server handling it and you'll need to setup an MX record on the domain to point to the server's address.  If you don't personally setup a server to handle it i'm sure there will be a charge from the company you bought the domain from to add e-mail to your domain.  If you get e-mail service from the company you purchased the domain from and pay the monthly fee, there will be a place on your account to set a forward address.  Google may do all of this for free but i've never set it up.